# what's the state of the process when it is multithread?

Tags: multithreading, process, pthreads

The state of a process is defined by the current activity of that process.

- new
- running
- waiting
- ready
- terminated

So if it is multi thread, has more than one state?

Comment: Depends. If the threads are implemented by a user-level library, then the kernel isn't aware of threads and they all will have the same state of the process they belong to. Otherwise, each will have it's own state.

Comment: Thanks, but i ask for the state of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Each thread of execution can be ready to run, running, or blocked. Other possible states exist on some platforms as well.